# How to get application root (full physical path) in OnApplicationStarted in MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, path, integrated-pipeline-mode

Until now I used:

```
Dim appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)
```

But today I moved my app from IIS6 to IIS7 and I get "Request is not available in this context" exception. This is due to Integrated mode pipeline in IIS7. I do not want to go to classic mode, so I am looking for a different way of getting the application path (which is "C:\SVN\L2E\trunk\Website").

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the full physical path of my MVC3 app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath.aspx) to get the virtual path and call [System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath.aspx) to map the virtual path to a physical one.

Comment: Thanks, works as it should :). Strange I could not find it myself

Answer (score 18):

use this:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```